# Inserting records Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping

Trying insert records into MySQL. This is my code

```
    sql = cursor.execute(f"SELECT inv_id FROM Investors WHERE name =\'{name}\'")
    pid = cursor.fetchone()
    try:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO team_members(inv_id,mem_name,picture,experience) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", (pid, port_name, headshot, work_ex,))
        #for li in so_links:
            #cursor.execute(("INSERT INTO team_members(social_media) VALUE %s", li))

    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

I am scraping this data and the same code was working fine earlier, I don't know what changed. This is the data.

> https://image.cypherhunter.com/upload/img/p/f81ee6c54642f53a38b5ad8d4c932eb4.jpg-resized

> Eddy Lazzarin
>
> a16z crypto
>
> Move fast, think big, building the next major franchises in
> technology.

This is how I am getting the data.

```
    try:
        port_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1[@class="app-name"]').text
    except:
        port_name = 'No name'
    print(port_name)
```

Why is it calling it a `tuple`? I tried this

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO team_members(inv_id,mem_name,picture,experience) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)" % (pid, port_name, headshot, work_ex,)
```

This gives a `syntax error`

Comment: Your first insert looks correct to me (though the select which precedes it does not).  What is the error message?

Comment: `Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type` . Don't know for which value it is saying so.

Comment: Did you open your database cursor with prepared statements turned on: `cursor = cnx.cursor(prepared=True)` ?

Comment: No. Like I said, this was working fine. Suddenly , it started giving errors. Should I try this?

Comment: If you don't know which value is a tuple, why don't you add some code to find out? (Hint: what does cursor.fetchone() return?)

Comment: @TurePålsson You are correct `(1,)` This is the output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You were right the `fetchone()` was wrong. Thanks for that, I didn't the take the hint. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do

```
pid = cursor.fetchone()
```

`fetchone` always returns a row, even if you just selected one value, so `pid` is probably a tuple of one element.

Answer (score 0):

This `(pid, port_name, headshot, work_ex,)` is a tuple. What arguments does the `cursor.execute(...)` function expect? Can you try removing the parentheses around those variables and have them each be arguments to `cursor.execute`?

Comment: This sounds like a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I have another program to send data to MySQL with the same code, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your INSERT line has an extra comma "," in the tuple (at the end). So it is getting the wrong number of arguments in the `execute()` call.

Comment: A redundant comma is allowed at the end of an expression list. Refer to [section 6.15](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists) of the manual.